# Replacement Part for Shower Faucet

Tags: plumbing, shower

My shower faucet handle disconnected from what I believe is part of the thermostatic mixer valve:
[image]

I believe that I can simply reconnect the handle when I get a replacement part, but I can't find the part anywhere online.  On a tag on the side, it has the following data: R120SSBP TYPE P ASSE 1016 A112.81.1.  It is a UFC American Standard part.

[image]

Does anyone know where I could get a replacement part for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can start out by taking it to your home store. While they lack in many plumbing areas, they do stock many different types of cartridges. Next, try a plumbing supply store. If they don't have it in stock, they'll know how to order it for you.

Comment: I'd go straight to a plumbing supply store. Odds are good the guy at the counter will know what he's looking at before you've finished explaining the problem to him.